# Multiple input for running program

Tags: c, linux, bash, redirect, pipe

I have the following C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char buf[64];
    gets(buf);
    printf("Your input: %s\n", buf);
    gets(buf);
    printf("Your input: %s\n", buf);
}
```

I want to send data to the program using pipes or redirection. The problem is that the program don't wait for the second gets to enter new data.

e.g

```
$ echo "a" | ./test
```

Output:

```
Your input: a
Your input: a
```

How can I send let the program wait for the user input at each gets using pipes or redirection.
P.S I don't have persmission to write to /proc/$pid/fd/0 and I don't have to change the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1.) DO NOT use `gets()`.
2.) try `scanf("%64s", buf);`
This prevents from buffer overflow. There may be better solutions. Just my first idea what you may use.

Comment: Thank you but I don't have to change the code.

Comment: You don't want to change it? or you cannot? Sorry, I didn't read the last sentence in question. But I still don't understand what it means.
To my first answer - it's not solution, just a few tips.

Comment: @Enkeli `scanf("%63s", buf);`, not `scanf("%64s", buf);`

Comment: @الطيب Is your question "How to make the program wait for input from the user after the piped data has ended?" so that the first `gets` should get `a` and the second should wait for user input?

Comment: @CoolGuy A huge mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pipes `|` to input data to a command, it is disconnected from the (input portion) of your terminal. `gets` reads the first line `"a\n"` and writes this to the `buf` as `"a\0"`. Then it hits the end of the pipe, or EOF (end of file).

Your second `gets` then does nothing (as there is nothing to read after EOF) and lets `buf` alone; `buf` still contains `"a\0"`, which is duly printed.

Further hints:

- When doing I/O, which can inherently fail at any time, you have to check for errors after each and every call, or bad things will happen. Train yourself to do this and save lots of debugging time.
- Never do an I/O like `gets(buf)` because it will lead to buffer overflows, the bane of computing security. If you input arbitrary data, you must use a call that lets you limit the number of bytes written. The man page for `gets` contains the sentence "Never use this function" right at the top. You can find other, better functions, `read` being a baseline, and if you are in C++ there will be plenty of other standard solutions for that.

Comment: `buf` does not contain the newline character.